# Problema con el cors - Jax-rs

Tags: java, webservice, jax-rs

Teniendo este codigo en front

```
let persona = {
    "idPersona": 0,
    "nombres": "Andres",
    "apellidos": "Henao",
    "email": "andresh@gmail.com",
    "telefono": "+54 30234151"
};

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
    let respuesta;
    if (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 201) respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.response);

    console.log(respuesta);
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/WebServices/webapi/personas/addPersona");

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF8");

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(persona));
```

Con este return en el web service /addPersona

```
return Response.status(200).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                .entity().build();
```

El navegador me manda el error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/WebServices/webapi/personas/addPersona' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

No sé si tenga relacion pero, desde hace poco tiempo, al acceder al web service por el navegador, envés de retornar un 405, retorna un 404.

Otro dato es que accediendo con un api tester, el webservice sí me funciona.

Comment: Let es de javascript. Entonces, la pregunta es de Java o Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

¿Estás usando spring? Si es así podes probar agregando esta clase:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer{

   @Override
   public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
       registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: no estoy usando spring, estoy trabajando con el arquetipo de jersey-quickstart-webapp

Comment: Ok, nunca lo use sin Spring, pero te dejo un enlace que puede ser lo que estas buscando
https://www.baeldung.com/cors-in-jax-rs